# ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel error when i try to startup an idle instance

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to duplicate a DB. After I created the db, modify the tnsnames and listener, started services in Windows (I am making this on windows 10) I still can't startup the instance. If I try to start again I get the this:

```
SQL> conn sys/ADMIN@dbname as sysdba
Connected to an idle instance.
SQL> startup
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
SQL> startup 
SP2-0642: SQL*Plus internal error state 2133, context 3114:0:0
Unsafe to proceed
ORA-03114: not connected to ORACLE
```

Comment: Please edit the question and show complete startup commands and complete error list. You mention ORA-03113, but show ORA-3114.  thanks

Comment: Could it be this:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168957/getting-an-error-when-trying-to-start-the-database-end-of-file-on-communication